# Viewing Live Photos on PC

Tags: photos, photos.app

I have downloaded the HEIC and MOV files. I want to be able to view them as if on an Apple device: click the image to play the video. Google Photos does this for photos uploaded to drive but I want to be able to do this for photos downloaded on my PC.

Comment: The "Live Photo" is the **.MOV** _file_, it's just a very short video clip. You can just play it to see that same thing as if on the **iPhone**.

Comment: @user3439894 I realize that but it is feels much more intuitive to be able to "play" a still picture. I have tried Amazon Photos as well and seems to work as well. There must be an app on Windows that is able to do this for files on my PC.